# Validate URL query parameters existance by regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate an URL by existance of certain query parameters.
For example, I want to validate an URL string beginning with `/questions` only if it has the query string parameters `previous` and `next`.

I could come up with this solution : `/questions\?(previous|.+&previous)=.*&next=.*`
That could validate this URL if `previous` parameter is placed before the `next` parameter.

Could you please tell me if there is an elegant way (without having to make an or like `((previous|.+&previous)=.*&next=.*|(next|.+&next)=.*&previous=.*)` ) to write this regex so that it becomes independant regarding the order of the `previous` and `next` parameters, without having ?

Comment: @anubhava I use Java (java.util.regex package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can shorten the current regex by eliminating the unnecessary alternation and replacing it with an optional group:

```
(previous|.+&previous) ===> (?:.+&)?previous=
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:.+&)?previous=` matches one or zero sequences of one or more characters other than a newline followed with `&` (so, this can be present or absent from the string) and then `previous=`.

Next, you can just impose two lookaheads that will require both `previous` and `next` parameters:

```
/questions[?](?=(?:.+&)?previous=)(?=(?:.+&)?next=)
             ^^^                 ^^^^             ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rC5eT3/1)

These `(?=...)` constructs (positive lookaheads) fail a match if their subpattern is not found after the current position in the string. So, both the previous and next params must be in the string for the string to match. The order of the params is not important because lookaheads are executed at the same place in the string, they do not consume characters.